# How to fix this "object is possibly null" error in typescript without disables strictNullChecks

Tags: typescript

Here is my typescript code :

```
const form  = document.querySelector('form');


if (form != null ) {
    const data = new FormData(form);
    for (const pair of data) {
        console.log(pair);
    }
    // OR
    for (const pair of data.entries()) {
        console.log(pair);
    }
}

document.getElementById("form_file")!.onchange= function(e: Event) {
    let file = (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files[0];
    }
```

I've tried :

```
let file = (<HTMLInputElement>e?.target)?.files[0];
```

and

```
let file = (<HTMLInputElement>e!.target)!.files[0];
```

How to make it works without using the disables `strictNullChecks` option in `tsconfig`?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is regarding the `files` array and not the `e.target`  HTMLInputElement, so, what you should actually be trying to do, is to assert if files is `null`  or `undefined` before trying to access the first index.

You can do it like:

```
// the "?.[0]" will make it only try
// to access the index 0 if `files` is different from null or undefined
document.getElementById("form_file")!.onchange= function(e: Event) {
    let file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files?.[0];
}
```

Or this way:

```
document.getElementById("form_file")!.onchange= function(e: Event) {
    let file;

    if((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files){
        file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Free typed, unchecked and probably wrong, but to get rid of possibly null issues i would look to nest - it can't be null if your code only executes if i.e. file exists or e.target && e.target.files exists.

```
const file = document.getElementById("form_file");

if (file) {
  file.onChange = function(e: Event) {
    if (e.target && e.target.files) {
      let file = e.target.files;
    }
  }
}
```